# How to import my thunderbird settings from Thunderbird 68 to thunderbird 78?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I just removed the thunderbird version from the Ubuntu repositories by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove thunderbird
```

I installed thunderbird 78 from the [thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/) site. It did not pick-up the previous profile (it seems to be a self-contained package as it did not require installation).
Is there a way to do this manually. I have a lot of mail accounts configured and would prefer, not setting them up manually.

Comment: Have you tried an online search for moving Thunderbird profile from one computer to another? Manually transferring an existing profile to a new Thunderbird installation on the same machine might be identical.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the tip. Indeed it should. I have not figured out yet where the new version searches for profiles.

Comment: Your Thunderbird profile *was* at `/home/<user_name>/.thunderbird`. Note the period. It indicates that it's a hidden file. When you uninstalled Thunderbird, you may have also removed that folder - but perhaps not. If you haven't deleted it, you can copy it to the new profile. If you have deleted it, you will need to recreate it.

Comment: @KGIII The profile of my old installation indeed was and is in `~/.thunderbird`. It was not deleted as I did not purge thunderbird. The 78 version of thunderbird however does not pick that profile. Reinstalling v. 68 also gives me back access to my mail accounts. At the moment I have both versions "installed". As I mentioned, I think the 78 thunderbird is a self-contained package that is not really installed.

Comment: You can copy/paste the profile. You *might* also be able to change it. Open Thunderbird, click on Help, click on Troubleshooting Information, and then scroll down a bit and click on Profiles. Even if it's not installed, it should tell you where it has stored the profile. Copy your data to that folder. That *should* sort you out.

Comment: Thank you, the location was indeed also in '~/.thunderbird'. But it seems that there is a reason for profile not being picked up. After i replaced the new profile folder with the old one,  I get XML Parsing Error: undefined entity Location: chrome://messenger/content/messenger.xhtml Line Number 1640, Column 9:
        <toolbarbutton id="appmenu_customize"
--------^ ....so I will probably bite the bullet and reconfigure, or stay for a while with 68, and return at a later point.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? 20.04 LTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT to reflect change in question:

Thurderbird installed from the site creates a new profile by default on Linux, but it is possible to make it use the original profile.

1. Open a terminal, change to the folder containing thunderbird and run `./thunderbird -Profilemanager`.
2. Select your profile, set it as default and open it.

Comment: the second paragraph, solved it for me. thx.